# Calling a method with Guid parameter using Reflection after using CodeDomCompiler to compile assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, compilation, guid

I'm trying to call a method from reflection :

```
bool ApproveUser(Guid userId)
```

I'm compiling the assembly using the .NET `CodeDomCompiler` component, where the class containing the method resides, and the method is being compiled to

```
{Void ApproveUser(System.String, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef)}
```

which is something completely different from what I would expect. Is this normal behaviour for the `Guid` parameter and return type to be transformed into something like that? Any hint is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT : Calling the method :

```
Guid request = new Guid("25867C0D-F2FB-6A6A-AC61-FF0000852B58");
object[] args = new object[1] { request };
object classInstance= compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("FooClass");
MethodInfo methodInfo = classInstance.GetType().GetMethod("ApproveUser");
bool result = (bool)methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, args);
```

I would expect the method to get successfully called, instead I receive the following exception :

```
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.
```

EDIT 2 : I changed the parameter type from `Guid` to `int`:

```
public bool ApproveUser(int smthg)
```

The compiled version is now

```
{Void ApproveUser(Int32, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef)}
```

Comment: I think you are looking on two completely different methods

Comment: "I'm trying to call a method from reflection" - please show us exactly how

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I thought so too, but there is only one such method inside that assembly

Comment: @AlexBarac that is very strange - different parameters, different return type. Make sure you are loading correct assembly

Comment: is your method `private` ?

Comment: @Selman22 I wouldn't expect that to appear unless `BindingFlags` were specified; default is public-only, IIRC

Comment: @MarcGravell yes but, I'm asking for `bool ApproveUser(Guid userId)` , if it's private it may be a problem. as you said bindingflags gets public methods by default. if both methods are public then this should throw exception on `GetMethod`, because it would find more than one match right?

Comment: @Selman22 No, it's an implementation of an `OperationContract` inside a WCF.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1(v=vs.110).aspx) of `GetMethod`:

```
var methodInfo = classInstance.GetType()
                .GetMethod("ApproveUser", new[] { typeof(Guid) });
```

If your method is private try specifying `BindingFlags`:

```
var methodInfo = classInstance.GetType()
                .GetMethod("ApproveUser", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Comment: `methodInfo` is in this case `null`

Comment: @AlexBarac then: the method you want isn't there; have a look at what *is* there (`GetMethods`) - we can't tell from here

Comment: @MarcGravell I totally agree with you, what I want isn't there. What is there, beside the methods that are provided by .NET, is only that which I have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

After several more tests, I found out that the `CompileAssemblyFromDom` method from the  `CodeDomProvider` behaves weird when parameters are of primitive types or structs inside the assembly. Therefor, `string`, `int`, etc, as well as their correspondent `String`, `Int32` and nullable versions, together with `Guid`, when set as return type or parameter type in a method, will be transformed to something similar to what was mentioned in the question. I also tested with different random classes, and the method header will look similar to the original, when using only real classes:

```
StreamWriter ApproveUser(Stream smthg)
```

Will be compiled to

```
{System.IO.StreamWriter ApproveUser(System.IO.Stream)}
```

This led me to the idea that if I use `object` instead of the primitive types I was using, the compile result would be satisfactory. Indeed,

```
object ApproveUser(object userId)
```

will be compiled to

```
{System.Object ApproveUser(System.Object)}
```

which is then accessible through reflection the way I expect it to be.
Apparently this is some kind of problem with the compilation process provided by the `CodeDomProvider`. Hope this helps others as well.